# Excel sum of mutiple match and multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

[image]

Hi I want a sum of 183 for  criteria "D" and "mp1"(yellow)
Currently my best result is 133.It adds all mp1 but stop at first "D"
THe other result 18 : add multiple "D" but stop at first "mp1"
I need both
Thanks

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: I'm using office 365. So if filter function can help I'm fine with it.

Comment: `=SUM(FILTER(FILTER(B2:G9,A2:A9=B12),B10:G10=B13,0))`

Comment: Works great but If found some people use excel 2016 and not office 365 so filter doesn't work :( any workaround ?

Comment: SUMPRODUCT:  `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:G9*(A2:A9=B12)*(B10:G10=B13))`